# Activity Direction Animation

Tags: android

I want to create theme in which I can apply an activities transition : When you start a new Activity there is a slide right-to-left, but when you press the back button to return to the previous Activity, there is a slide left-to-right animation but using only XML files. No Additional code will require it can be done by only applying theme in Manifest file It solve the problem not exactly one is going left and other is going right....

push_left_in.XML

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false" >

     <translate
         android:duration="500"
         android:fromXDelta="100%"
         android:toXDelta="0" />

     <alpha
         android:duration="500"
         android:fromAlpha="0.0"
         android:toAlpha="1.0" />

 </set>
```

push_left_out.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:shareInterpolator="false" >

         <translate
             android:duration="500"
             android:fromXDelta="0"
             android:toXDelta="-100%" />

         <alpha
             android:duration="500"
             android:fromAlpha="1.0"
             android:toAlpha="0.0" />

     </set>
```

push_right_in.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false" >

     <translate
         android:duration="500"
         android:fromXDelta="0"
         android:toXDelta="100%" />

     <alpha
         android:duration="500"
         android:fromAlpha="1.0"
         android:toAlpha="0.0" />

 </set>
```

push_right_out.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
         <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:shareInterpolator="false" >

             <translate
                 android:duration="500"
                 android:fromXDelta="-100%"
                 android:toXDelta="0" />

             <alpha
                 android:duration="500"
                 android:fromAlpha="0.0"
                 android:toAlpha="1.0" />

         </set>
```

style.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <resources>

         <style name="mytheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
             <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/theme</item>
         </style>

         <style name="theme">
             <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@style/push_right_in</item>
             <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@style/push_right_out</item>
         </style>



     </resources>
```

Comment: Are you finishing the first activity when you start the second activity?

Comment: but I want go to second activity after pressing back key from third activity

Comment: Dont finish your first activity when you start the second one. Because the animation will be applied when you finish the first one. So that you are getting two animations, 1 for finishing the first activity and 2 for starting your second activity

Comment: He is doing the same.